# The definite article with an indefinite abstract

Tags: articles, definite-article

The definite article is used for specific things. In the following sentence the noun "*disappearance*" is not specific (no one is missing):

***The** disappearance of a person cannot go unnoticed* .

Why is the definite article used here?

Comment: It's a specific thing (the disappearance) happening to an unspecific thing (a person).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Disappearance" is not indefinite. It is abstract. "Disappearance" represents one of many types of condition or state that relate to a person such as presence, absence, health, etc.

> The absence of a prisoner is supposed to be noticed by the guards.

> The doctor said that the health of patients is the only responsibility of a physician.

I think you are confusing indefinite with abstract. The abstract does not specify an individual, to be sure, but a specific abstraction can be distinguished from other abstractions.